# First element in natural ordering from Scala Set

Tags: scala, set, scala-collections

I have Scala immutable `Set`

```
Set("c", "b", "a")
```

I want to take first element in natural ordering from it.

Code that works for me is

```
TreeSet(set.toList: _*).firstKey
```

It isn't very readable though. Is there any shorter/easier solution for it?

Comment: Why not `Set("c", "b", "a").headOption`?

Comment: What does "natural ordering" mean?

Comment: @JensSchauder I understand it as defined for Java types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: @cchantep in this case it returns `Some(c)`, for my set I expect getting just `a` or exception if set is empty

Comment: Using option is safer and more idiomatic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I'm completely missing what you mean by 'natural ordering' I think it's just `Set.min`

```
Set("c", "b", "a").min 
//> res0: String = a
```

with exception on the empty set, as desired:

```
Set[String]().min
//> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.min
```

Comment: Natural ordering is defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html I hope, not sure if there is Scala equivalent though

Comment: Yes, this is the same. `min` uses an implicit `Ordering` but the doc says this is equivalent to `Ordered` and the doc for _that_ says "Ordered should be used for data with a single, natural ordering (like integers) while Ordering allows for multiple ordering implementations. An Ordering instance will be implicitly created if necesssary". So `min` will give your natural ordering.